# Using maps in a native App

Tags: mapkit, cordova

Building an ios app using apache cordova 2.1. Building and styling is going fine but maps are not.

I found a plugin for the maps but simply cannot get it to work:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/MapKit

I also found an example html file but could :
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/MapKitPlug/example

1/
So i added the MapKit framework into xcode which was pretty straight forward:
http://blog.thinketg.com/blog/david-brainer-banker/xcode-4-tips-adding-frameworks-to-your-project

2/
Added the .m and .h files

3/
Added and linked the .js file to my index.html

4/
copied the example html above.

5/
Added the Mapkit to the .plist file as per the instructions

When I try to run the map I get the following errors:

```
2012-11-05 14:21:29.505 sawdaysApp[25398:c07] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2012-11-05 14:21:30.895 sawdaysApp[25398:c07] CDVPlugin class MapKitView (pluginName: MapKitView) does not exist.
2012-11-05 14:21:30.895 sawdaysApp[25398:c07] ERROR: Plugin 'MapKitView' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in Cordova.plist.
2012-11-05 14:21:30.896 sawdaysApp[25398:c07] FAILED pluginJSON = [null,"MapKitView","showMap",[]]
2012-11-05 14:21:30.896 sawdaysApp[25398:c07] CDVPlugin class MapKitView (pluginName: MapKitView) does not exist.
2012-11-05 14:21:30.896 sawdaysApp[25398:c07] ERROR: Plugin 'MapKitView' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in Cordova.plist.
2012-11-05 14:21:30.897 sawdaysApp[25398:c07] FAILED pluginJSON = [null,"MapKitView","setMapData",[{"diameter":1000,"offsetTop":25,"lon":-123.104446,"buttonCallback":"cbMapCallback","lat":49.281467999999997,"height":360,"atBottom":true}]]
```

I assuming that the error is with the MapKitView in the CDVPluggin, but really not sure.

Has anyone had any experience with this and succeeded?

Comment: FYI I have followed this problem further (https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en-GB&fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/dnCg1t97X2k) No-one seems to be able to give me a response. I have altered the .m and .h files in accordance with the first response from the above the link in this comment. Still no joy and I still get the same errors.

Comment: Basically if anyone knows how to get maps working in iOS using Apache Cordova 2.1 I would love to know how. Following the guides I could find I could not.

Comment: FYI: I you want to solve this issue in later versions of Cordova take a look at the discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811642/phonegap-cordova-2-7-0-mapkit-plugin-getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THIS WORKS. AT LAST :)

1 - Follow this guide to start the app http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html

2 - Download and add mapkit plugin native files (all of them) in the plugins folder and the .js file in the www folder. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/MapKit.
Make sure you drage the pluggins folder to the pluggins folder in xcode otherwise the app will not link the files properly.

3 - Whitelist * to whitelist all the domains and Add the plugin reference on Cordova.plist MapKitView as value and key

4 - Donwloaded and included into the sawdaysTestApp/pluggins folder JSONKit.h and JSONKit.m https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

5 - Change mapkit.h and .m

```
#ifdef CORDOVA_FRAMEWORK
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
#else
#import "CDVPlugin.h"
#endif

to

#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
```

and

change mapkit.m

```
from

#ifdef CORDOVA_FRAMEWORK
// PhoneGap >= 1.2.0
#import <Cordova/JSONKit.h>
#else
// https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit
#import "JSONKit.h"
#endif


to

    #import "JSONKit.h"
```

1. Get the example from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iPhone/MapKitPlug/example/index.html. Copy and paste entire example into index.html.

7 - Change the index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="MapKitPlug.js"></script>
```

to//

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="MapKit.js"></script>
```

8 - Run the simulator. click the show map button.

Comment: Good to know you've got this to work. I was going to start working with maps in cordova soon so have starred this one for future reference :)

Comment: If I were you I would use Appcellerator. Although the only main lng used is JS perfomance and control is much more advanced than cordova. We were road testing the 2 (i was hoping cordova would win) and appcellerator won. One problem with cordova is the speed of its development recently vs the lack of speed with the available pluggins. EG these maps, the pluggin was simply of date and some of the objective C code needed updating which kind of defeats the purpose of cordova...

Comment: Thanks for the update, Titanium Appcellerator is the other development platform we're considering working with too so thanks for pointing the above out!

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to add two things:

1, That as of Cordova 2.3.0 the filename

```
Cordova.plist
```

Is now

```
yourProject-Info.plist
```

*yourProject* being what ever your project name is.

2, I found that you still need to 'Link Binary With Libraries' by doing the following:

- Click on your project
- Select Build Phases
- Click the arrow on Link Binary With Libraries
- Click Add
- Search for MapKit.framework and click Add