# Phonegap (Cordova) 2.7.0 + Mapkit Plugin + Getting Started

Tags: cordova, mapkit

I am trying to get the [PhoneGap Mapkit Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/MapKit) up and running.

This is what I did so far:

1. I added the [MapKit framework](http://blog.thinketg.com/xcode-4-tips-adding-frameworks-to-your-project/) into my xcodeproject:

   ```
   Framework/
     MapKit.framework
     ...
   ```
2. Downloaded and added [MapKit](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/MapKit) plugin native files to the plugins folder:

   ```
   Plugins/
      AsyncImageView.h
      AsyncImageView.m
      CDVAnnotation.h
      CDVAnnotation.m
      MapKit.h
      MapKit.m
   ```
3. Downloaded and added [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) plugin native files to the plugins folder:

   ```
   Plugins/
      ...
      JSONKit.h
      JSONKit.m
   ```
4. Downloaded and added [`MapKit.js`](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iOS/MapKit/MapKit.js):

   ```
   www/js/
      MapKit.js
      ...
   ```
5. Included the [`MapKit.js`](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iOS/MapKit/MapKit.js) file in the index.html:

   ```
   ...
   <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/MapKit.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
   ...
   ```
6. Added the Plugin to the `config.xml` file:

   ```
   ...
   <widget>
     ...
     <plugins>
       ...
       <plugin name="MapKitView" value="MapKitView" />
     </plugins>
     <access origin="*" />
   </widget>
   ```
7. Added a `showMap`function to my app object in the `js/index.js` file:

   ```
   var app = {
     ...
     onDeviceReady: function() {
       app.showMap();
     },
     showMap: function(){
       window.plugins.mapKit.showMap();
       window.plugins.mapKit.setMapData({
             buttonCallback: function(){
               alert(arguments[0]);
             },
             height: 360,
             diameter: 1000,
             offsetTop: 25,
             lat: pins[0].lat,
             lon: pins[0].lon
          });
       window.plugins.mapKit.addMapPins([{
               lat:49.281468,
               lon:-123.104446,
               title:"Nitobi HQ",
               pinColor:"purple",
               selected:true
          }]);
     }
   }
   ```

After running this nothing happens. No Map no Errors...

**Console Output**

```
-> Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
-> Resetting plugins due to page load.
-> Finished load of: file:///..pathto../iPhone%20Simulator/6.0/Applications/...SOMEKEY.../PhoneGapIOSExample.app/www/index.html
-> DEPRECATION NOTICE: The Connection ReachableViaWWAN return value of '2g' is deprecated as of Cordova version 2.6.0 and will be changed to 'cellular' in a future release.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
cordova 2.7.0 can't be used anymore to submit apps to the apple store, so I deleted my fork of the plugin.

For newer cordova versions use
https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin

The original plugin can be found [here](https://github.com/imhotep/MapKit)

Comment: The above link is no longer valid, jcesarmobile - could you update the link please

Comment: Not yet i will certainly give a try. thanks for providing updated link.

Comment: you can't use phonegap 2.7.0 anymore neither if you want to submit the app to the apple store, so what's the point of downvoting the answer? let it go down